# Merge multiple events from RDBMS in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are capturing Change data capture from different tables from a RDBMS database. Each individual change is treated as an event. All the events are published into a single Kafka topic.  Every event (message) is having the table name as header. We need to cater certain Use cases, where we need to merge  multiple events and populate the output.
Entire thing is happening in real time.

We are using Apache Kafka.

Comment: Perhaps if you can explain what technology you're wanting to use, and what you've tried so far, people will be able to help better. It's quite a broad question you're asking.

Comment: Dear Robin,

Following is my Use Case sequence:

1. Changes are happening in a RDBMS in two tables T1 & T2 , but the changes are independant not in a single transaction.
2. The changes (events - E1 & E2) are captured by a CDC tool and published into a single Kafka Topic
3. The Kafka topics contain multiple partitions
4. We need to capture certain fields from Event E1 & certain fields from Event E2 and prepare a data set to populate a output system.

We need a mechanism to track how the events E1 & E2 are related against a time frame. The events E1 & E2 have one common field that is ID

Comment: Dear Robin, kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean exactly by merging events, but this seems to be in Kafka streams domain.
You can design each of your events using streams and  ktables, for which you'll apply a Kafka streams topology ( joining streams of events and applying some business logic for instance)

But do you need more technical suggestions?

Yannick

Comment: Yes. Different events are coming on same kafka topic. I need to combine two different events and extract information from these two events, but the timing of this events are not fixed.

Comment: @D You can use windowing operations to capture time differences, and edit the TimestampExtractor to capture differing times when events should be joined within the window